# Почему Gson конвертирует дату в другой формат?

Tags: java, gson

При заполнении Arraylist, дата выглядит так: 1-9-2020, а после действия toJson() дата превращается в "сен 1, 2020" можно ли убрать это? или использовать что то другое?

Comment: Смотреть здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873020/gson-date-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В GSON можно установить формат даты следующим образом:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
   .setDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz").create();
```